# Browser window height on mobile firefox v23

Tags: css, mobile, browser, height

I have this minimal code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width height=device-height">
    <title>test</title>
    <style>
        html, body {
          height: 100%
        }
        #container {
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #0f0;  
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">&nbsp;</div>
</body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert(window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('container')).height); 
    </script>
</html>
```

on a server at:

http://catplusplus.org.uk/catpsite/portfolio/test.html

so this code will alert the height of the container div which should be 100% of the browser window.

I've included the meta-viewport tag in the header which should ensure mobile zooming is set to 1:1 in terms of pixels.

when I load this on a LG nexus 4 running android on Chrome I get a height of 519px in portrait and 311px in landscape - which I think is pretty much right (screen size minus UI etc)

when I load this on the same phone using Firefox (v23) I get a height of 1134px in portrait and 718px in landscape, this seems wrong.

Is this a known issue, am I missing something simple, can someone fill the gap in my knowledge here please?

Thanks

James

p.s. just tested on Safari on iPhone 4 also seems off, reporting 540px for both portrait and landscape....